# Outage: Google Doclist API 2LO results in 500 Internal Error messages

Tags: google-docs-api

as of about 3 hours ago every call to the Doclist API using 2-legged OAuth started failing with "500 Internal Error" messages.

We have verified this from multiple systems (App Engine and local apps) using different libraries, and across domains in Asia, US and Europe.

The problem does NOT occur if normal user authentication is used - only 2LO is affected.

Unfortunately this issue affects thousands of students using our tools.

http://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3233&thanks=3233&ts=1347419864

Jan

Answer (score 0):

This is tracked at http://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3233 and the fix should be live very soon.

UPDATE: everything is now back to normal